# Queue when using Amazon SES?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, queue, bulk, amazon-ses

i implement a small bulk-mail sending tool in rails based on the Amazon SES service and action mailer. i read that amazon queues my sent messages before sending them out itself.

so my question: does that mean i don't need to implement a message-queue myself (e.g. 50 mails per 5 minutes) against blacklisting and does amazon that job for me and i just transfer 5000 mails to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to divide them into groups of 50 (see documentation Note at http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/) first.  Also see "Managing your Sending Activity" on that page (it's ajax-driven, so there's no other URL).  I would use Delayed Job for the queue: http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job.

Comment: thank you. can you edit the link to the part with group of 50? the link just links to the documentation index.